# Upper bound on size of derivation in CFG

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Suppose $G$ is a $CFG$ with $m$ variables, in which the right-hand side of all production rules has length at most $\ell$. Show that if $A\Rightarrow^*_G\varepsilon$, then there is a derivation of no more than $\frac{\ell^m-1}{\ell-1}$ steps by which $A$ derives $\varepsilon$. How close to this bound can you actually come?

Comment: Please state the question in the title! That way it is easier to recognize for anyone who visits later.

Comment: Sorry, because this is my first time posting a question, I am not very skilled

Comment: Hint, what happens when $m=1$? What happens when $m=2$? Restrict to small $\ell$ such as $\ell=2$ to ease exploration as well.